# What's this hole with a lock symbol on the back of my monitor?

Tags: display

When I inspected my monitor I found a hole with a lock symbol (pictured below).

What is this? What is the function of this hole?

[image]

My monitor is a Samsung Syncmaster SA100.

Comment: -1, this question shows zero research effort. You didn't even try to open the users's manual, or google for "K lock". Or even crop your photo to something more reasonable.

Comment: @Slai That's where interests of SO users and SO owners diverge. If we try hard enough, we can probably end up with a question "How do I login to Facebook?" which will be the first result for "facebook login" query. That will be just great for site stats. The benefit to the users, on the other hand, will be a net negative as we will have to clean up a steady stream of "answers" which will read "OK, where's the damn login form???7777"

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev How could he google for "k-lock" if he didn't know it was a lock back then?

Comment: @TheBitByte There's a letter K and a lock icon right there in the picture. Alternatively googling a few words from the question title (e.g. `lock hole monitor`) would give similar results.

Comment: So, this site didn't support google-able question? I searched using my country language and fail to find the answer.

Comment: If you search for "thing" then no, that is not something to search with. If you used "hole lock computer" or "hole lock monitor" like your question originally had, it would show you matching results

Comment: I used "lobang dibelakang monitor" keyword

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Looking at the image, I did not recognise the |< symbol as a "K", nor the 'blob' as a lock - and I knew what the slot is for!!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's called a Kensington lock, or Kensington security slot, and it provides an attachment point for a cable to prevent your monitor from being moved or stolen.

[image: laptop with Kensington lock attached]

*from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot)*

Comment: It's funny how you say "[...] to prevent move / steal of your monitor." but then you show an image of a laptop. But that exactly it. It is very used on stores (like Stapples, for example). I haven't seen any use besides there.

Comment: I found first the picture of a laptop:), the same way it can protect monitors printers... too. I know there are some offices (and probably coffees and libraries offering internet access too) where these locks are used.

Comment: Note that these locks are also common in computer labs for schools. They use this to lock the desktop tower and the monitor to the desk so that they can leave the lab open and people can't (easily) steal the equipment.

Comment: @JamesTrotter We don't have that problem here. And if we do, they are usually locked with a stronger steel lock, going around the screen and on a hole on "specially-made" horizontal computer cases. (I have it between quotes because those are pretty much standard cases, but have a bit of metal with a hole, where the cable goes through.) The cable is then attached to the table/desk. I had these at school and saw a bank with these too.

Comment: Given that the bolt of a Kensington lock is fairly small, one might cynically say its purpose is not to prevent theft, but to obviously damage the case if the thief just rips it out, thereby reducing the resale value.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I had often thought of that also, but I think it's still very useful in some situations.  For example, if you have your laptop at a library or a Starbucks, you could secure it to a table while you go to the restroom.  The lock/cable would be enough to prevent someone from casually walking off with it - at least not without making a scene.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz In Hungary we have a saying: "opportunity makes a thief". That is what Kensington locks good for.